# How to add mochawesome report generator in webdriverIO?

Tags: webdriver-io, mochawesome

I've been trying the below in `wdio.config.js` file on webdriverIO to no avail. I have:

```
  reporters: ['dot',['mochawesome',{
        outputDir: './Results', reportTitle: 'My Custom Title',  showPassed: false, marge: '--saveHtml'

    }], 
],
    mochawesomeOpts: {
    includeScreenshots:true,
    screenshotUseRelativePath:true
    },
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1 --reporter-options reportDir=Report,reportFilename=Test_Report",
    "generateMochawesome":"marge   --reporter-options reportDir=Report,reportFilename=Test_Report"
  },


"dependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.9.1",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "^3.1.5",
    "mocha-simple-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "mochawesome-merge": "^4.2.0",
    "mochawesome-screenshots": "^1.7.3",
    "npm": "^7.20.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/dot-reporter": "^7.9.0",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.9.1",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.9.1",
    "chromedriver": "^92.0.1",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.2.0",
    "wdio-mochawesome-reporter": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71156983/i-am-trying-to-generate-mochawesome-report-with-webdriver-io-framework-json-file#

Answer (score 0):

I went through this and ended up downgrading some packages, here is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "webdriverio-tests",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "",
    "private": true,
    "keywords": [],
    "scripts": {
        "test": "wdio test/wdio.conf.ts --spec ./test/specs/integration.e2e.ts",
        "generateMochawesome": "marge Results/results-0-0.json --reportTitle 'My Project Results'"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@wdio/cli": "^7.27.0",
        "@wdio/dot-reporter": "^7.26.0",
        "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.27.0",
        "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.26.0",
        "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.26.0",
        "chromedriver": "^107.0.3",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "typescript": "^4.9.3",
        "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^8.0.0",
        "wdio-mochawesome-reporter": "^4.0.0",
        "wdio-wait-for": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "mochawesome-report-generator": "^3.1.5"
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).