# I am trying to generate Mochawesome Report with webdriver.io framework json files are not created

Tags: node.js, report, webdriver-io, mochawesome

I have added below dependencies in my project

"mochawesome-report-generator": "^6.0.1",
"wdio-mochawesome-reporter": "^4.0.0",
"@wdio/dot-reporter": "^7.16.14"

And added in wdio.conf file the below configuration

```
reporters: [
    'dot', 'mochawesome',
  ],
  reporterOptions: {
    outputDir: './mochawesome-results', //json file will be written to this directory
  },
```

When I run the spec file in the console log i see the below:

```
 "dot" Reporter:
FF..

 "mochawesome" Reporter:
{"stats":{"suites":1,"tests":2,"passes":0,"pending":0,"failures":2,"start":"2022-02-17T09:29:32.518Z","end":"2022-02-17T09:30:46.131Z","duration":73613,"testsRegistered":2,"passPercent":0,"pendingPercent":0,"other":0,"hasOther":false,"skipped":0,"hasSkipped":false,"passPercentClass":"success","pendingPercentClass":"danger"},"suites":{"title":"","suites":[{"title":"Findashop Tile (iphone11.ios.14_5.myproximus-dev_app)","suites":[],"tests":[{"title":"TC-Appointment in a shop-Validate -appointment in a shop- tile","fullTitle":"TC-Appointment in a shop-Validate -appointment in a shop- tile","timedOut":false,"duration":13590,"speed":"fast","pass":false,"fail":true,"pending":false,"code":"","isRoot":false,"uuid":"ca459c43-d36d-4914-992d-545e7d44a41a","parentUUID":"f8720287-98c6-43f0-a043-9a06bc7bd53d","skipped":false,"isHook":false,"context":"[{\"title\":\"Session Id\",\"value\":\"cf2e255d-74b7-4fe8-99f6-c19147bf8202\"}]","state":"failed","err":{"name":"unknown error","message":"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil","estack":"unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)\n    at whenAcceptPushNotification (/Users/dipikamishra/myproximus-rn/src-dise/legacy-features/__e2e__/common.ts:284:14)\n    at Object.givenLandingToDashboard (/Users/dipikamishra/myproximus-rn/src-dise/legacy-features/__e2e__/common.ts:144:3)\n    at Object.givenAuthenticatedUserInServices (/Users/dipikamishra/myproximus-rn/src-dise/services-features/__e2e__/common.ts:90:5)\n    at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/dipikamishra/myproximus-rn/src-dise/services-features/__e2e__/services/findashop.spec.ts:17:5)","stack":"unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)\n    at whenAcceptPushNotification (/Users/dipikamishra/myproximus-rn/src-dise/legacy-features/__e2e__/common.ts:284:14)\n    at Object.givenLandingToDashboard (/Users/dipikamishra/myproximus-rn/src-dise/legacy-features/__e2e__/common.ts:144:3)\n    at Object.givenAuthenticatedUserInServices (/Users/dipikamishra/myproximus-rn/src-dise/services-features/__e2e__/common.ts:90:5)\n    at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/dipikamishra/myproximus-rn/src-dise/services-features/__e2e__/services/findashop.spec.ts:17:5)"}},{"title":"TC-Appointment in a shop-Validate web view for -appointment in a shop-","fullTitle":"TC-Appointment in a shop-Validate web view for -appointment in a shop-","timedOut":false,"duration":60001,"speed":"fast","pass":false,"fail":true,"pending":false,"code":"","isRoot":false,"uuid":"92b510d1-bc7d-4fc1-a103-b5409b52c2bb","parentUUID":"f8720287-98c6-43f0-a043-9a06bc7bd53d","skipped":false,"isHook":false,"context":"[{\"title\":\"Session Id\",\"value\":\"cf2e255d-74b7-4fe8-99f6-c19147bf8202\"}]","state":"failed","err":{"name":"Error","message":"Timeout of 60000ms exceeded. The execution in the test \"Findashop Tile TC-Appointment in a shop-Validate web view for -appointment in a shop-\" took too long. Try to reduce the run time or increase your timeout for test specs (https://webdriver.io/docs/timeouts.html). (/Users/dipikamishra/myproximus-rn/src-dise/services-features/__e2e__/services/findashop.spec.ts)","estack":"Error: Timeout of 60000ms exceeded. The execution in the test \"Findashop Tile TC-Appointment in a shop-Validate web view for -appointment in a shop-\" took too long. Try to reduce the run time or increase your timeout for test specs (https://webdriver.io/docs/timeouts.html). (/Users/dipikamishra/myproximus-rn/src-dise/services-features/__e2e__/services/findashop.spec.ts)\n    at Test.Runnable._timeoutError (/Users/dipikamishra/myproximus-rn/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:432:10)\n    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/Users/dipikamishra/myproximus-rn/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:244:24)\n    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)\n    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)","stack":"Error: Timeout of 60000ms exceeded. The execution in the test \"Findashop Tile TC-Appointment in a shop-Validate web view for -appointment in a shop-\" took too long. Try to reduce the run time or increase your timeout for test specs (https://webdriver.io/docs/timeouts.html). (/Users/dipikamishra/myproximus-rn/src-dise/services-features/__e2e__/services/findashop.spec.ts)\n    at Test.Runnable._timeoutError (/Users/dipikamishra/myproximus-rn/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:432:10)\n    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/Users/dipikamishra/myproximus-rn/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:244:24)\n    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)\n    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)"}}],"pending":[],"root":false,"fullFile":"","file":"","passes":[],"failures":["ca459c43-d36d-4914-992d-545e7d44a41a","92b510d1-bc7d-4fc1-a103-b5409b52c2bb"],"skipped":[],"duration":73592,"_timeout":0,"uuid":"f8720287-98c6-43f0-a043-9a06bc7bd53d","beforeHooks":[],"afterHooks":[]}],"tests":[],"pending":[],"root":true,"fullFile":"","file":"","passes":[],"failures":[],"skipped":[],"duration":0,"_timeout":0,"uuid":"cd45c312-f5ae-47d3-bf5f-7812f7a3d5fa","beforeHooks":[],"afterHooks":[]},"copyrightYear":2022}{"stats":{"suites":1,"tests":2,"passes":2,"pending":0,"failures":0,"start":"2022-02-17T09:31:01.781Z","end":"2022-02-17T09:31:53.225Z","duration":51444,"testsRegistered":2,"passPercent":100,"pendingPercent":0,"other":0,"hasOther":false,"skipped":0,"hasSkipped":false,"passPercentClass":"success","pendingPercentClass":"danger"},"suites":{"title":"","suites":[{"title":"Findashop Tile (emulator-5554.android.11.app-devmyproximus-release_apk)","suites":[],"tests":[{"title":"TC-Appointment in a shop-Validate -appointment in a shop- tile","fullTitle":"TC-Appointment in a shop-Validate -appointment in a shop- tile","timedOut":false,"duration":22979,"speed":"fast","pass":true,"fail":false,"pending":false,"code":"","isRoot":false,"uuid":"3da11fe9-2796-4283-9474-76858256595b","parentUUID":"53d3c250-f4ec-463c-aa19-ce5602ae1ab3","skipped":false,"isHook":false,"context":"[{\"title\":\"Session Id\",\"value\":\"40aabd96-f546-4fb5-8912-c2de4277d69e\"}]","state":"passed","err":{}},{"title":"TC-Appointment in a shop-Validate web view for -appointment in a shop-","fullTitle":"TC-Appointment in a shop-Validate web view for -appointment in a shop-","timedOut":false,"duration":28175,"speed":"fast","pass":true,"fail":false,"pending":false,"code":"","isRoot":false,"uuid":"aae85dd9-fe6d-419d-8ea8-10f225ab9267","parentUUID":"53d3c250-f4ec-463c-aa19-ce5602ae1ab3","skipped":false,"isHook":false,"context":"[{\"title\":\"Session Id\",\"value\":\"40aabd96-f546-4fb5-8912-c2de4277d69e\"}]","state":"passed","err":{}}],"pending":[],"root":false,"fullFile":"","file":"","passes":["3da11fe9-2796-4283-9474-76858256595b","aae85dd9-fe6d-419d-8ea8-10f225ab9267"],"failures":[],"skipped":[],"duration":51156,"_timeout":0,"uuid":"53d3c250-f4ec-463c-aa19-ce5602ae1ab3","beforeHooks":[],"afterHooks":[]}],"tests":[],"pending":[],"root":true,"fullFile":"","file":"","passes":[],"failures":[],"skipped":[],"duration":0,"_timeout":0,"uuid":"37442765-57d4-4717-bd25-52a6dd25a163","beforeHooks":[],"afterHooks":[]},"copyrightYear":2022}
```

Now the problem is I dont see the mochawesome-results directory getting created and no json files getting created. Where is this directory or is it only printing in console log and not generating any json file? What more configs i should be doing?

Answer (score 0):

As Mochawesome report had release very long back. Seems not compatible with wdio v7.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31970507)

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue.
In my case, adding 'outputFileFormat' field to 'mochawesome' configuration resolved it:

```
    reporters: [[
       'mochawesome', {
            outputDir: './mochawesome-report',
            outputFileFormat: function(opts) {
                return `results.json`
            }
       }]],
```